# Shell script to parse Names Ip port and priority

Tags: bash, file, loops, line

I have a bash script and within it I create and execute a python script which is using lxml etree to parse through a huge xml file to extract the following data:

The data may have multiple servers or just one or none and each server will have 4 values of data name, ip, port and priority:

```
name1
1.1.1.1
port#
priority 
name2
1.1.1.2
port#
priority 
name3
1.1.1.3
port#
priority
```

I need to read this file and make an ssh connection to the ip and port specified in the file. If the connection is successful to the first IP, I would "break", else I would try the second connection and so on...

I currently have a loop defined in the script which has 2 specific IP's that are hard set as variables and looks like this:

```
echo -e "\n${YELLOW}Checking HOST SSH Connectivity.$NOCOLOR"
for HOST in $HOST1 $HOST2; do
  ERRno=0
  echo -e "${YELLOW}Attempting to connect to $HOST From $IP${NOCOLOR}"
  if cat < /dev/tcp/$HOST/22 </dev/null; then
   echo -e "\n${CYAN}Connection To $HOST Over Port 22 From ${YELLOW}$IP ${CYAN}Seem's Good. Starting SSH Session. ${YELLOW}To End SSH Session Hit CTRL-C.$NOCOLOR"
    if ! /usr/bin/ssh -c aes256-ctr -F "$SSHCONF" -p 22 "$HOST" "$CMD" ; then
     echo -e "${RED}Please Check Connectivity, SSH Session Ended.$NOCOLOR"
    fi
  else
    echo -e "${RED}Unable to connect to $HOST, Customer should make sure Port 22 Outbound is Allowed Through Firewall from $IP to $HOST.$NOCOLOR"
    ERRno=3
  fi
# If we had a good session (on the 1st server), break out, we are done
  [[ $ERRno -eq 0 ]] && break
  if [[ $HOST != $HOST1 ]]; then
    echo -e "${RED}No More Servers To Try. Unable To Establish Any SSH Session.$NOCOLOR"
    exit $ERRno
  else
    echo -e "${YELLOW}Trying Next Server...${NOCOLOR}"
  fi
done
```

However reading a file that can vary in length is where I am getting confused.

How can I accomplish this? 
Should I build and array and index?
Should I do a while read loop?

Either way please provide examples.

Comment: If you're already using Python, why not do this part in Python, as well?

Comment: The rest of the script is written in bash and it huge and I dont want to rewrite it... its just simpler..

Comment: OK, why not have the Python program create a bash script to be sourced rather than a data file.  The script can be an unrolled loop and exit after finding the right host...

Comment: That is a good idea thanks I can try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer to "how do I read an indeterminate number of lines" is a `while` loop.

```
while read -r name && read -r address && read -r port && read -r priority; do
    : stuff
done <file
```

A more common arrangement, both for usability and readability, is to lay out the data as one record per line, each field in a separate token (or if you have field values with multiple tokens, use a dedicated separator character, such as a comma, which makes your input a CSV file).

```
while read -r name address port priority; do
    : stuff
done <<'__HERE'
  name1 1.1.1.1  80 25
  name2 1.1.1.2 119  3
  name3 1.1.1.3 443 50
__HERE
```

To use a comma as the delimiter, (locally) set the shell variable `IFS` to a comma.

Comment: I think this was the simplest solution :) thanks so much had a major brain fart.